# adding attribute id to select option dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Here's my code.

**HTML**

```
<select id="drop_opts">
            <option>1<option>
            <option>2<option>
            <option>3<option>
        </select>
```

**Backbone**

```
this.collection.each(function(value){
                $('#drop_opts option').each(function(){
                    $(this).attr('id', value.cid);
                });
            });
```

The result I'm getting is

```
<select id="drop_opts">
            <option id="c3">1<option>
            <option id="c3">2<option>
            <option id="c3">3<option>
        </select>
```

What am I doing wrong? thanks,

Comment: what is cid in value.cid ?

Comment: why do you put two each ? what is this.collection

Comment: @C-link cidmodel.cid 
A special property of models, the cid or client id is a unique identifier automatically assigned to all models when they're first created. Client ids are handy when the model has not yet been saved to the server, and does not yet have its eventual true id, but already needs to be visible in the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in each iteration of collection, you are changing the value of all option

```
var $opts = $('#drop_opts option');
this.collection.each(function (value, i) {
    $opts.eq(i).attr('id', value.cid);
});
```

---

If you want to use the value as id, there is no need for collection loop

```
$('#drop_opts option').attr('id', function(){
    return $(this).val()
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r39XH/)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want them give the value id?

```
this.collection.each(function(value){
                $('#drop_opts option').each(function(){
                    $(this).attr('id', $(this).val());
                });
            });
```

Or what could be in the value.cid? What kind of data you want to pass?

Comment: cidmodel.cid 
A special property of models, the cid or client id is a unique identifier automatically assigned to all models when they're first created. Client ids are handy when the model has not yet been saved to the server, and does not yet have its eventual true id, but already needs to be visible in the UI.

Comment: You need to iterate (for,foreach) through the value.cid too,to match it's value to the option.